# How to call enrichment API from DHS?

Tags: marklogic

I heard that MarkLogic Data Hub Service does not allow outbound REST call.
In case, if we want to consume external enrich purpose API, what is the best practice to consume it instead of calling API from code in the custom step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the call external to DHS, such as in a Lambda or with Step Functions if on AWS, and push the result into MarkLogic's DHS.

Comment: Thanks! Let me verify, Is there any approach to manage those process as flow/step in Data Hub Framework? I am afraid if we make the call external, we have to manage the process separately from flows/steps.

Comment: You cannot manage this from inside flows/steps. You have to either do this upfront, or use an external orchestration tool that can push this information as part of initial payload, or as options to one of the subsequent steps.